# Perl RegEx for all digits with possibility of decimal and negative

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that downloads weather data from weather bug.  It was parsing fine until the temperture got cold and now my negative numbers are being tossed out.

```
# sample input: 0.0mm|1028.11s|75%|-4|
# expected output: precip:0.0 pressure:1028.11 humidity:75 temp:-4
$output =~ s/[^\d.|]+//g
```

The units are already known so all alpha characters get tossed, with the percent symbols and so on, but I need the decimal point from precipitation and barometric pressure in the above, but I will also need the negative sign for colder temperatures.  So far the negative sign is being tossed out from the above regex.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post an input along with expected output.

Comment: edited post to reflect.  everything gets stored into the array so i can prefix each element appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[^\d.|-]+
```

Try this.See demo.Add a `-` to your character list.

http://regex101.com/r/xV4eL5/3

Answer (score 0):

Split up the line then remove the characters that shouldn't be there:

```
use v5.14;

my $string = '0.0mm|1028.11s|75%|-4|';

my @keys = qw(precip  pressure humidity  temp);

my %hash;
@hash{ @keys } = map { s/[^0-9.-]//gr } split /\|/, $string;

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper( \%hash );
```

The part of this program that does the substitution is inside the `map`:

```
s/[^0-9.]//gr
```

It uses my favorite Perl 5.14 feature: [the `/r` flag that returns the modified string instead of the count of the number of substitutions](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/).

I also don't use `\d` to match digits since Perl now lets that match all the UCS digit characters. Instead, I specify exactly `0-9`. See [Know your character classes](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/01/know-your-character-classes/).

The rest is just a way to but the extracted data into a hash with the keys you show in your output.